# mySQL .NET API - Delete all data from table

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, api

I'm trying to figure out if there is an easy way to delete all the data in a table using the mySQL .NET API. The only slightly more tricky part to this is that in the C# code, the business logic can be run in both cases where there is, or isn't, data in teh table.  So in some regards I almost need an If statement...

Currently I am using the following code, but it doesn't seem to ever delete data...

```
        string deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM `data`.`currentData`";
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(deleteSQL, conn);
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated! 
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You should use the TRUNCATE command instead.  That will also reset any auto_increments you have.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: Simply changing to `TRUNCATE` doesn't answer the OP's question.  Consider offering this suggestion as a comment instead.

Comment: Thanks Phil, still getting used to how to do things here.

Answer (score 3):

The sql looks good, make sure you call `cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();` and the connection is properly setup, and the user has DELETE permission.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a dumb idea. But what about just dropping the table and recreating it?